# Scraping an IE Window

Tags: c#, .net, interface, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I'm developing system which interfaces with two systems to load/store data.

1. An ancient terminal program which uses a 3rd party DLL to Bridge .NET and this
   system, sending keystrokes and receiving them back. This part is no
   problem as the technology is clear.
2. A 128bit SSLed web app, launched in it's own Window from a website. It's not running inside any kind of Java nastyness, just HTML and a tad of JavaScript.

   I want to somehow scrape the contents of this window so I can get access to a document available within it. At a minimum, this would be waiting for the user to navigate to the right page, then click a button in an app I write, which would then go and look for the right window, parse the source of the current page and download the file.

   In an ideal world, it would be automated from the start, requiring only a single click from the user in my app to navigate to the right page, login, and download the document.

Is #2 doable to any extent, using commercial of free components.

Comment: Have you looked at using `WebClient` to retrieve the HTML/JS and using the HTML Agility Pack to parse it? And of course figure out what requests to issue by looking at the traffic using fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the browser Internet Explorer (I'm reading the question title), just reference this `Microsoft Internet Controls` `COM` library:

[image: Microsoft Internet Controls]

Then I have done the scraping like this:

```
var internetExplorerShells = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();

string html = null;
foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in internetExplorerShells)
{
    if (ie.Document != null)
    {
        var url = ie.LocationURL;

        // If the Internet Explorer Address contains _configuration.ScrapingUrl
        if (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(
            url,
            _configuration.ScrapingUrl,
            CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            html = ie.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
            if (html != null)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then just install [HTMLAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) via NuGet and start scraping the html:

```
var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
```

Comment: Accepted as the answer for thoroughness, even though I can't remember what I was trying to do 8 years ago when I asked this.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is hard to achieve, even more if you don't target a specific browser vendor like FF or Chrome etc.

Suggestions:

1) Use `System.Net.WebClient` to download the source code directly from webserver.

2) If you need some user interaction that can't be (or you don't want to) simulated by some automation code, you can use projects like **webkitdotnet**, then you can create a WinForm app that has a browser inside it. You will have full access for contents of that browser.

Webkitdotnet project page: http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/

Comment: The window always launches in IE because that's what the user uses. I'd like to attach to the existing IE window.